# Order by Lastname and ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two DB tables

```
 FAMILY
 ------
 family_id (PK)
 address
 ....

 PERSON
 -----
 person_id (PK)
 lastname
 birthday
 family_id (FK)
 family_role (numeric >1 male, 2 female, 3 male(child), 4 female(child)
 ....
```

I want to create an alphabetic family list, in which the lastname of the oldest person must be leading and ordered by the FAMILY_ROLE. I was trying something like:

```
 select *
 from person, family
 where person.family_id = family.family_id
 order by lastname, family_role
```

Now this is not working, because last names in the same family doesn't have to be the same. So this is working

```
 select *
 from person, family
 where person.family_id = family.family_id
 order by family_id, family_role
```

But that doesn't give me an alphabetic list.
The output must be something like:

```
 Test street 1 - New York (family_id = 100)
 John Bla (family_id = 100 | person_id =10 | family_role=1) 
 Sara Bla (family_id = 100 | person_id =13 | family_role=2)
 ----
 Apple street 1 - New York (family_id = 45)
 Rick Cha (family_id = 45 | person_id =1 | family_role=1)
 Lin Cha (family_id = 45 | person_id =5 | family_role=2)
 Jean App (family_id = 45 | person_id =3 | family_role=4)
 ----
 Cherry street 114 - New York (family_id = 23)
 Becky Cha (family_id = 23 | person_id =122 | family_role=2)
 ----
```

Can someone help me? Database version MSSQL 2008.

Also please keep in mind that people can have the same last name, but belong in a different family (see the Cha families in the output example).

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure the ColdFusion tag on this is appropriate? It's just an SQL question, innit? Even if you're running CF, it won't be part of the equation here.

Comment: In case, you are still waiting for further input: Could you, please, add the data to the tables, which should result in the expected output?

Comment: I have just edited the question

Comment: I hoped for enough data in the input tables to actually (re)produce your expected output. (You might want to use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to provide the same.) Your description is somewhat OK - but does lack some detail: (i) You want "lastname" checked - but seem to have first and last name stored in the "lastname" column. (ii) What exactly do you mean by "alphabetic list" - you require to sort by age, not by name… (iii) If the parents had different last names, with the wife being older than the husband - what should that look like in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to associate the last name of the oldest person in a family with everyone in the family.  You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a cte/subquery for this:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Family_ID ORDER BY Age DESC) AS RN
              FROM Person
              )
 SELECT p.*,f.*
 FROM person p
 JOIN family f
   ON p.family_id = f.family_id
 JOIN cte 
   ON p.family_id = cte.Family_ID
   AND cte.RN = 1
 ORDER BY cte.lastname
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY Family_ID`  then for each unique `Family_ID` value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

So the cte/subquery gives you a way to see who the oldest person is and access their last name in one step, then you can `JOIN` to this to use in your `ORDER BY`.

Note:  Old-style joins should also be avoided, and so I updated that as well, and I'm assuming you have an `Age` field in your `Person` table to determine who the oldest is, the `cte` may require updating based on actual table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to decide how you are going to choose which family member is going to determine the alphabetical placement of the family. For example if family #100 has Jon Doe and Jane Smith, will it come in the Ds alphabetically or the Ss?

You could write the query like this

```
SELECT f.*,p.*,A.FamilyNameOrderKey FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
          Min(lastname) As FamilyNameOrderKey, Family_id
    FROM
          person
    Group by Family_id
    ) As A
INNER JOIN
    family f
ON
    A.family_id = f.family_id
INNER JOIN
    people p
ON
   p.family_id = f.family_id
    )
```

Order by A.FamilyNameOrderKey
This will sort by the last name of the alphabetically first last name in each family